# Flexbox - How to do space-around in vertical?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, flexbox

Probably it's a noob question, but I'm wondering how it's possible do something similar "space-around" but in vertical direction.

This:
Half-pad 
Element 
pad 
Element
pad 
Element 
half-pad

This: 
 Half-pad 
 Element 
 pad 
 Element 
 pad  
 Element  
half-pad

I'm missing how to do half-pad too.

Doing direction: vertical misses initial and end space-around.

```css
.stabled {
  position: fixed;
  right:0px;
  top:0;
  width:15px;
  height:100%;
  z-index:95;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}

.stabled ul {
 position:relative;
 display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
 
 -webkit-flex-direction:column;
 flex-direction:column;
 
 height:100%;
 width:170px;
}


nav.stabled ul li {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 
.stabled li.firl {
 padding-left:0;
 padding-top:35px;
 }


.stabled:hover {
  position: fixed;
  width:170px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: Resolved. It was a different mistake because image sizes. Solution is simple: http://codepen.io/devtips/pen/OPQYav (Made by https://www.youtube.com/user/DevTipsForDesigners)

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer? It was really helpful for me. :-)

Comment: Done. And follow DevTips Travis Neilson... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved. It was a different mistake because image sizes. Solution is simple: codepen.io/devtips/pen/OPQYav (Made by youtube.com/user/DevTipsForDesigners)

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blueviolet
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```